# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire 5.0.0-rc.2 "

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, alamofire

I'm using `‘Alamofire’, ‘~> 5.0.0-beta.5’` via CocoaPods in my swift project . Now I'm trying to use `Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-rc.2)`.

Unfortunately I got the following error after applied  "pod install" command line:

> CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Alamofire":   In
>   Podfile:
>       Alamofire (~> 5.0.0-rc.2)

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the release is new (only 2 days ago), you first need to update your local specs repositories.

In your `Podspec` file, put this:

```
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.2'
```

On the terminal, run:

```
pod update
```

Then:

```
pod install
```

Output:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using Alamofire (5.0.0-rc.2)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There is 1 dependency from the Podfile and 1 total pod installed.
```

Comment: If still not working after doing this, delete **Podfile.lock** file from app folder and run `pod install` on the terminal.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe in some situations when other points so not work. Check this issue:

```
platform :ios, '9.0' // check platform :ios version

target "app_name" do
    pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.0.0-rc.3'
end
```

In my situation deployment target was set to 9.0 but Alamofire 5+ is on the 10.0 version.

```
/** Alamofire.podspec **/
...
s.ios.deployment_target = '10.0'
s.osx.deployment_target = '10.12'
s.tvos.deployment_target = '10.0'
s.watchos.deployment_target = '3.0'

s.swift_versions = ['5.0', '5.1']
...
```

Just replace `platform :ios, '9.0'` to `platform :ios, '10.0'` and the problem will be solved. [Source: Alamofire.podspec](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Alamofire.podspec#L12)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `pod search Alamofire` first and then use the version which is on the list. And if the version is not neccessary, you can just use `pod 'Alamofire'`.